# JQuery Menu toggle button

Tags: jquery

This is a script of a drop down menu that I created. I want to add when link clicked to close the drop down. Any ideas?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
    $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="menu-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-bars" style="font-size:36px"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="logo">
    LOGO
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#ourTeam">Our Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#imageGallery">imageGallery</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<style>
  .showing {
        max-height: 34em;
  }
<style>
```

Comment: Please include runnable code.

Comment: what link are we talking about? What navigation bar are we talking about? We can't see your HTML.

Comment: just edited the code!

Comment: What does the `showing` class do? Assuming it shows/hides the elements, your code already works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/yeopf7g8/. If it's not working for you check the console for errors elsewhere in your logic

Comment: Sorry guys its my first question here!! I just edited again the code!The code is working fine.Just i want to add function when the link is clicked to hide the drop down menu.This is the question. :)

Comment: What link do you want the click event attached to?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-icon").on("click",function() {
    $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu ul li a").on("click",function() {
    $("nav ul").removeClass("showing");
    });
});

Comment: i added the same function just with a event .removeClass and it works but it doesnt take in stackoverflow :/

Comment: Just a note, you don't need a second document.ready, you can have as many functions as you like within a single one.

Comment: i fixed it Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.menu a').click(function(){
    $('.menu').hide();
});
```

This works. Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/kpxnejLf/1/